# Error with Python Flask : jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'form' is undefined

Tags: python, flask

Here is my app drop.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, render_template,request, url_for
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms import DateField
from datetime import date

app = Flask(__name__,template_folder='template')

class DateForm(Form):
    dt = DateField('Pick a Date', format="%m/%d/%Y")


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template(
        'index.html',
        data=[{'name':'red'}, {'name':'green'}, {'name':'blue'}],data2=[{'name':'John'}, {'name':'Mouton'}, {'name':'Blah'}])

@app.route("/" , methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test():
    select = request.form.get('comp_select')
    if select == "red":
        col = "Rouge"
    elif select == "green":
        col = "Vert"
    elif select == "blue":
        col = "Bleu"

    select2 = request.form.get('comp_select2')
    if select2 == "John":
        usr = "Personne"
    elif select2 == "Mouton":
        usr = "Animal"
    elif select2 == "Blah":
        usr = "Autre"

    text = request.form['text']

@app.route('/', methods=['post','get'])
def home():
    form = DateForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        mydate =  form.dt.data.strftime('%x')
    return render_template('index.html', form=form)

    return(str(col)+str("\n\n")+str(usr)+str("\n\n")+str(text)+str("\n\n")+str(mydate))


if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True,host="0.0.0.0")
```

Here is my index.html under a template folder :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>DatePicker Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( ".dtpick" ).datepicker();
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form class="form-inline" method="POST" action="{{ url_for('test') }}">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">Please select</span>
            <select name="comp_select" class="selectpicker form-control">
              {% for o in data %}
              <option value="{{ o.name }}">{{ o.name }}</option>
              {% endfor %}
            </select>
<form class="form-inline" method="POST" action="{{ url_for('test') }}">
        <span class="input-group-addon">Please select</span>
            <select name="comp_select2" class="selectpicker form-control">
              {% for o in data2 %}
              <option value="{{ o.name }}">{{ o.name }}</option>
              {% endfor %}
            </select>
<form method="POST">
            <input name="text">
<form method="post" action="">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ form.dt(class="dtpick") }}
    <button type="submit">Go</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
</form>
</form>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I need that users select a name, a color, enter a free text and pick up a date.
I have tried to modify the python code and the html file but I always have this error that form is not defined.

If I remove the part of Datepicker, everything is working. (Dropdown menus, free text, button)

Comment: Why to you have a route, a `return` and a `<form>` twice ? Correction: at least twice

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs in your `index()` function. You do not provide `form=form` to the `render_template()` call as you do in the `home()` function. Adding this should at least fix this problem.
Just to be clear: As there are multiple functions for the same route, you should start by making the first one work. You need a form in the first function but the following leads to a RuntimeError due to a missing token:

```
@app.route('/')                                                                     
def index():                                                                        
    form = DateForm()                                                               
    if form.validate_on_submit():                                                  
        mydate =  form.dt.data.strftime('%x')                                      
    return render_template(                                                         
        'index.html',                                                               
        data=[{'name':'red'}, {'name':'green'}, {'name':'blue'}],data2=[{'name':'John'}, {'name':'Mouton'}, {'name':'Blah'}],    
        form=form                                                                   
    )
```

We can solve the RuntimeError by setting a secret key just after instantiating Flask (just an example key):

```
app.secret_key = 'aaaaaaaaa'
```

After that I get a form in my browser.

Comment: Hi, I already tried it but that don't fix the problem. I have the same error message.

Comment: That is funny. I get a `RuntimeError: A secret key is required to use CSRF.` instead. The template seems to be working...

Comment: I run it directly with python3 drop.py. Maybe you do it another way ?

Comment: Same here.  OK. I think my RuntimeError happens, when I try to create the form argument for the render_template call. Sorry. But how do you instantiate DateForm?

Comment: form = DateForm()

Comment: Now it works whit your modifications but I can't print the value of the date with return or take it into a variable. It seems that in : ` if form.validate_on_submit():                                                  
        mydate =  form.dt.data.strftime('%x')`  The code never go inside the if.

Comment: You should look into your server debug output. I get a "TypeError: The view function for 'test' did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement." At least the version of test() you posted does not work out for me.